# Please advise on how to solve sql logic error near "Ref" syntax error

Tags: mysql

```
 private void ExecuteQquery(string QueryData) 
    {
        SetConnectDB();
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
        sqlCmd.CommandText = QueryData; 
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCmd.Dispose();
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
```

sqlcmd commandtext = querydata appear to be an issue when i run the program.

```
private void btnAddField_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

        string QueryData = "Insert into details(Customer Ref, First Name, Last name, Address, Mobile, " + "Email, Gender, DOB, Nationality, Prove)"
                                + "values('" + btnCustomerReference.Text + "','" + btnFirstName.Text + "','" + btnLastName.Text + "','" +
                                btnAddress.Text + "','" + btnMobile.Text + "','" + btnEmail.Text + "','" + chkGender.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1 +
                                "','" + chkNationality.Text + "','" + chkPOI.Text + "')";

       ExecuteQquery(QueryData);
       UpLoadData();
    }
```

The error pointed at ExecuteQquery(QueryData). I've tried all kind of method to solve yet no result.

[command below is declared in instance variable]

```
public SQLiteConnection sqlConn;
    public SQLiteCommand sqlCmd;
    public DataTable sqlDT = new DataTable();
    public DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    public SQLiteDataAdapter DB;
```

Comment: Including spaces within table/column identifiers is just asking for trouble. Don't do it.

Comment: Hmm, why is this tagged MySQL but the code indicates SQLite? What DBMS do you really use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I identified two issues with your query

1. Some of your column names contain spaces in between so use single quotes  `''`
2. And there is no space before values

so edit your query like this :

```
string QueryData = "Insert into details('Customer Ref','First Name','Last name','Address','Mobile', " + "'Email','Gender','DOB', 'Nationality','Prove')"
                                    + " values('" + btnCustomerReference.Text + "','" + btnFirstName.Text + "','" + btnLastName.Text + "','" +
                                    btnAddress.Text + "','" + btnMobile.Text + "','" + btnEmail.Text + "','" + chkGender.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1 +
                                    "','" + chkNationality.Text + "','" + chkPOI.Text + "')";
```

> And also make sure that all data that you are inserting in the table
> matches the datatype with the respective column.

Comment: Did you check that all the column names that you have used in the query match exactly with the those in the table?  Also, check their case

Comment: Not sure if this is language specific - but in PHP you need to use backticks and not single quotes round column names.